# ASP.NET MVC how to handle the default empty value for dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I create a dropdown list by using ASP.NET MVC helper like this,

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("Group","-please select a group-")%>
```

and I get the html like this，

```
<label for="GroupId">Group:</label>
<select id="GroupId" name="GroupId"><option value="">-please select a group-</option>
<option value="15">Business</option>
<option value="16">Friends</option>
<option value="17">Others</option>
</select>
```

The default option is "-please selecta group-" and the value is empty.

How can I validate the select value to see if it's empty?
I mean if user doesn't choose a group, how can I know it and give user a error message.
Now, the code only shows exception error, because the value is empty for the default option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of Group in the Action will be 0.
You could test if Group is zero and call `ModelState.AddModelError`.
It would be better, if it was possible to explicitly set the value of the default item in the dropdownlist, but that is not possible in the `Html.DropDownList`.

Anyway I use the overload:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("Group",Model.GroupList ,"-please select a group-")%>
```

With that you  have one Property in the Model for the list of Groups and one for the key of the selected Group. If I use

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("Group",Model.GroupList ,"-please select a group-")%>
```

then ModelState.IsValid is always false for me.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I could not test if Group is zero. How do u do it?

Comment: Hi Eric,
Model.Group==0 if you use strongly typed view.
(int)ViewData["Group"]==0 if you use ViewData as a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to accomplish this:

**1. First approach: Custom validation**

**Model**

```
namespace MyApplication.Models
{
    public class GroupModel
    {      
        public GroupList SelectdGroup { get; set; }
    }
 
    public enum GroupList
    {
       Business, Friends, Others
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using MyApplication.Models
@model GroupModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <b>Select Groupe: </b> 
 
    @Html.DropDownList("SelectdGroup", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(GroupList))),"--Select Group--")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("SelectedGroup")
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HtmlHelperDemo.Models;
 
namespace MyApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            return View();
        }
 
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(GroupModel model)
        {           
            var selectedValue = model.SelectdGroup;
            
            if (selectedValue == "")
        {
           ModelState.AddModelError("SelectdGroup", "The Group is required");
        }
    
            
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Second approach: Using the attribute Required**

Just add the “Required” attribute before the "**SelectdGroup**" field of the model and remove the check on the field "**SelectdGroup**" in the controller.

**Model**

```
namespace MyApplication.Models
{
    public class GroupModel
    {   
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "the Group is required.")]   
        public GroupList SelectdGroup { get; set; }
    }
 
    public enum GroupList
    {
        Business, Friends, Others
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HtmlHelperDemo.Models;
 
namespace MyApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            return View();
        }
 
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(GroupModel model)
        {           
            var selectedValue = model.SelectdGroup;                 
            
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```